# Use another variable into an array in struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem. I want to create a program that reads from a file different elements - vectors, arrays, scalars. In the struct I have variables like dimension, name, a symbol of element and value etc. I get errors when I use structs

```
primal.c:10:18: error: ‘dimension’ undeclared here (not in a function)
         double V[dimension];
                  ^~~~~~~~~
primal.c:28:18: error: ‘dimensionX’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘dimension’?
         double M[dimensionX][dimensionY];
                  ^~~~~~~~~~
                  dimension
primal.c:28:30: error: ‘dimensionY’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘dimensionX’?
         double M[dimensionX][dimensionY];
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
```

This is my whole program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

    struct Vector 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimension;
        double V[dimension];
    };
    typedef struct Vector wek;

    struct Scalar 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        double wartosc;
    };
    typedef struct Scalar ska;

    struct Array
    {
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimensionX;
        int dimensionY;
        double M[dimensionX][dimensionY];
    };
    typedef struct Array mac;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *wz, *wc;  
    int dimension, dimensionX, dimensionY;

    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    
    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
    exit(2);
    }
    


            
    
    struct Vector w1, w2;
    struct Scalar s1, s2;
    struct Array m1, m2;
    
    
    wek readVector(FILE *wz)
{
    wek w;
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &w.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &w.elementName[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &w.V[j]);
    return w;
}
    ska readScalar(FILE *wz)
{
    ska s;
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &s.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &s.elementName[0]);
    fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &s.wartosc);
    return s;
}
    mac readArray(FILE *wz)
{
    mac m;
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &m.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &m.elementName[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dimensionX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dimensionY; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &m.M[i][j]);
    return m;
}
    s1 = readScalar(wz);
    s2 = readScalar(wz);
    w1 = readVector(wz);
    w2 = readVector(wz);
    m1 = readArray(wz);
    m2 = readArray(wz);
    printf("Symbol %c, nazwa %s, wartosc %lf", s1.keyWord, s1.elementName, s1.wartosc);
    fclose(wz);
    fclose(wc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why that this is undeclared, I have for example first struct and I declared this variable.

```
    struct Vector 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        **int dimension;**
        double V[**dimension**];
    };
```

Edit
I edited my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

    struct Vector 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimension;
        double *V;
    };
    typedef struct Vector wek;

    struct Scalar 
    { 
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        double wartosc;
    };
    typedef struct Scalar ska;

    struct Array
    {
        char keyWord;
        char elementName[20];
        int dimensionX;
        int dimensionY;
        double **M;
    };
    typedef struct Array mac;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *wz, *wc;  
    int dimension, dimensionX, dimensionY;

    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    
    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
    exit(2);
    }
    


            
    
    struct Vector w1, w2;
    struct Scalar s1, s2;
    struct Array m1, m2;
    
    
    wek readVector(FILE *wz)
{
    wek w;
    w.V = malloc( sizeof *w.V * w.dimension );
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &w.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &w.elementName[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &w.V[j]);
    return w;
}
    ska readScalar(FILE *wz)
{
    ska s;
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &s.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &s.elementName[0]);
    fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &s.wartosc);
    return s;
}
    mac readArray(FILE *wz)
{
    mac m;
    m.M = malloc( sizeof *m.M * m.dimensionX * m.dimensionY);
    fscanf(wz, "%s", &m.keyWord);
    fscanf(wz, "%20s", &m.elementName[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dimensionX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dimensionY; ++j)
            fscanf(wz, "%10lf", &m.M[i][j]);
    return m;
}
    s1 = readScalar(wz);
    s2 = readScalar(wz);
    w1 = readVector(wz);
    w2 = readVector(wz);
    m1 = readArray(wz);
    m2 = readArray(wz);
    printf("Symbol %c, nazwa %s, wartosc %lf", s1.keyWord, s1.elementName, s1.wartosc);
    fclose(wz);
    fclose(wc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

but I get warnings, when I compiled with -Wall

```
primal.c:65:34: warning: ‘w.dimension’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     w.V = malloc( sizeof *w.V * w.dimension );
                                 ~^~~~~~~~~~
primal.c: In function ‘readArray’:
primal.c:83:34: warning: ‘m.dimensionX’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     m.M = malloc( sizeof *m.M * m.dimensionX * m.dimensionY);
                                 ~^~~~~~~~~~~
primal.c:83:49: warning: ‘m.dimensionY’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     m.M = malloc( sizeof *m.M * m.dimensionX * m.dimensionY);
```

The warnings are pretty self-explanatory - you haven’t assigned any values to w.dimension or m.dimensionX. Their values are indeterminate. You need to assign values to them before you can use them in the malloc call. – John Bode 5 hours agoPlease use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review – Rob 27 mins ago

Comment: `V` should be a pointer if the array size is unknown: `double *V`, etc.  Or... you need a constant: `#define DIMENSION (5)`, `double V[DIMENSION]`.  Looks like you want the flexibility of the first one.

Comment: Or you need to use a 'flexible array member' (FAM), which must be the last element in the structure.  `struct Vector { char keyWord; char elementName[20]; int dimension; double V[]; /* FAM */ };`. They are a part of C99 and beyond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration

```
double V[dimension];
```

`dimension` is not a *constant expression*, which means you’re declaring `V` as a variable-length array.  Unfortunately, VLAs may not be `struct` or `union` members.

**Edit**

Of course, that’s not why you’re getting the compiler error - the `dimension` you’re using in the array declaration is not the same `dimension` that you’ve declared in the `struct` type.  C has different name spaces for identifiers:

- label names (must be preceded by `goto` or followed by a `:`);
- tag names (must be preceded by the `struct` or `union` keyword);
- `struct` and `union` member names (must be preceded by an identifier followed by `.` or `->`);
- all other identifiers (variable names, function names, enumeration constants, etc.);

In the declaration

```
double V[dimension];
```

the compiler is looking for a `dimension` variable outside of your `struct` definition - there’s no way to specify that you want to use the member variable (which won’t work anyway for the reason given above).

**End edit**

In this case, you’ll need to allocate memory for `V` dynamically, so you’ll need to declare it as a pointer:

```
double *V;
```

and then after you read or compute the dimension allocate memory for it as

```
w.V = malloc( sizeof *w.V * w.dimension );
```

Comment: Flexible array members?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Maybe.  They’d have to allocate the whole `struct` instance dynamically, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign the length of an array inside a structure with another member of the structure.try to use a pointer and allocate it dynamically.Or if you don't want to use pointer,define a max macro for the dimension.